# my eclipse is unnormal

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

File->new project,
only appear two option, before there are many option choice, also I install android development tool, there is no item about that appear. I uninstall the eclipse and reinstall the eclipse, seem no change for this problem.
my system is under ubuntu 12.10 64bit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it using `apt-get`, I would suggest installing it from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: yes。 I download from google adt site using offline mode.I think is my eclipse problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably you used the central programs.
Try downloading directly from the site: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

The eclipse does not need an installation, you can download, and in the case of Lixux, assign permição need to run "sudo chmod-R + r eclipse"

Comment: before when start eclipse,new project, you will see many options, such as java,now my pictures just contain" General CVS two option". I use this one "http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html" and use "ADT-21.0.1.zip" package with offline install. I try several times. All things is normal before I update  the eclipse. I update the eclipse, then eclipse remind me some componet may not right,it colapse, then the ADT disappear. I uninstall the eclipse, reinstall it. but things always not change